# haskell STACK BUILD on windows gives permissions errors (rename)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Why do I get a permissions violation with stack build on windows? See below for version of stack and the error message about renaming files. This happens even when I run as ADMIN, so it seems to be more than just a folder's permissions issue.

(BTW, if this is a anti-virus issue, company policy does not let me turn off McAfee).

```
C:\CRIME\haskell-call>stack --version
Version 2.1.3, Git revision 0fa51b9925decd937e4a993ad90cb686f88fa282 (7739 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.2

C:\CRIME\haskell-call>stack build
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Already downloaded.
Already downloaded.
Already downloaded.
Decompressing ghc-8.8.3.tar.xz...

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\ysg4206\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3.tar.xz

Extracting  ghc-8.8.3.tar

Everything is Ok

Size:       2555330560
Compressed: 204702116
Extracting ghc-8.8.3.tar...
Extracted total of 10091 files from ghc-8.8.3.tar
C:\Users\ysg4206\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3-tmp1040\ghc-8.8.3\: renamePath:MoveFileEx "C:\\Users\\ysg4206\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\x86_64-windows\\ghc-8.8.3-tmp1040\\ghc-8.8.3\\" "C:\\Users\\ysg4206\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\x86_64-windows\\ghc-8.8.3\\": permission denied (Access is denied.)

C:\CRIME\haskell-call>stack --version
Version 2.1.3, Git revision 0fa51b9925decd937e4a993ad90cb686f88fa282 (7739 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.2

C:\CRIME\haskell-call>stack build
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Already downloaded.
Already downloaded.
Already downloaded.
Decompressing ghc-8.8.3.tar.xz...

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\ysg4206\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3.tar.xz

Extracting  ghc-8.8.3.tar

Everything is Ok

Size:       2555330560
Compressed: 204702116
Extracting ghc-8.8.3.tar...
Extracted total of 10091 files from ghc-8.8.3.tar
C:\Users\ysg4206\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3-tmp1040\ghc-8.8.3\: renamePath:MoveFileEx "C:\\Users\\ysg4206\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\x86_64-windows\\ghc-8.8.3-tmp1040\\ghc-8.8.3\\" "C:\\Users\\ysg4206\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\stack\\x86_64-windows\\ghc-8.8.3\\": permission denied (Access is denied.)
```

Comment: It might be worth checking out [this issue in the Stack repo](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1917).

Comment: Did that already